# How do i detect a cycle in a undirected graph and drop the edge with the maximum weight in that cycle?

Tags: algorithm, graph

I know DFS or union-find can be used to detect a cycle. But is there a quick way to find the edge with the maximum weight in that cycle?

Comment: Not any faster than just looking at all of them and remembering the biggest one you see.  DFS and union-find do not necessarily find the edges in any order of weight, just in order of how far they are from the starting node, so you have no idea which one of a cycle is largest, unless you're sorting by weight or something.

Comment: You wouldn't be trying to do [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8178072/finding-a-minimum-spanning-tree-given-the-old-mst-and-a-new-vertex-edges), would you?

Answer (score 0):

No, DFS and sequential search is the optimal solution. Just find the cycle and go through its edges to find the maximum weight edge. The complexity doesn't really matter here - you had to find the cycle anyway and the complexity of finding the maximum edge is the same.

Answer (score 0):

There's no good way to do this just once, but if you're going to iterate until the graph is acyclic, you'll leave a minimum spanning tree, which can be computed in linearithmic time.